# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxEx`ception: expecting OPEN, found 'from' near line 1, column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I have a project in Spring Boot 1.5 with `mysql` database. I have 2 entity classes `BackupOTP` & `OTP` and I want to copy data from `OTP` table to `BackupOTP` table using HQL. For that I have written this code.

```
Query query=session.createQuery("insert into BackupOTP from OTP where isExpired=:boolean");
query.setBoolean("boolean", true);
int i=query.executeUpdate();
System.err.println("i = "+i);
```

But I am experiecning the below exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
expecting OPEN, found 'from' near line 1, column 23 
[insert into BackupOTP from com.altafjava.central.entity.OTP where isExpired=:boolean]
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: why are you using where clause for insert?

Comment: It is necessary for our requirement. If OTP is expired then we need to back up otherwise we don't want to backup that's why we have taken isExpired=true

Comment: That's not valid HQL. Here's the documentation for insert statements: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-insert. Everything becomes smpler when you read the documentation.

Comment: What is the reason for down vote?

Comment: The reason is that you asked without first doing the most basic research: read the documentation about insert statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer.

> Actually, It was the problem with HQL syntax. My HQL syntax was wrong. I looked into [Hibernate insert query documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-insert) and modified my insert syntax like this

```
Query query=session.createQuery("insert into BackupOTP (otpId, createdTime, encryptedOTP, isExpired, updatedTime)"
+ " select otpId, createdTime, encryptedOTP, isExpired, updatedTime from OTP where isExpired=:boolean");

query.setBoolean("boolean", true);
int i=query.executeUpdate();
System.err.println("i = "+i);
```

> Now it is working.